# Ableton Live create video is greyed out

Tags: ableton-live

I have bought Ableton Live Suite but I cannot create a video from an audio track. Is it even possible? The create video functionality is greyed. Do I need to install some code or something?

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by a not supported QuickTime Version.
If QT is installed, try downgrading it. For eg with Haali Media Splitter & ffdshow.

This  ug was found 2015. But it may still be the problem.

Comment: Can you explain what to do with Haali Media Splitter & ffdshow? I'm having trouble understanding what they have to do with the QT version? Do you know what QT version is needed for Ableton?

Comment: Sorry. I guess I mixed somethings up here. I found the info on [link] (https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjer_SVqL7fAhWM6qQKHYuPCp0QzPwBegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fableton%2Fcomments%2F3a5vt0%2Fvideo_window_is_greyed_out%2F&psig=AOvVaw2ZGx_r2smFp9KxazImBzBm&ust=1545941812550997) Take a look here for recommendation [link] (https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/209773125-Using-Video-in-Live)